# value manipulation in nifi flow

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I have a file and sample data is below

```
23
48
90
99
23
21
```

now I need to add 5 for every record and output should be as below

```
28
53
95
104
28
26
```

I have used GETfile processor in nifi and next I have taken replace text value but I am unable to find a solution can any one help me with this

my replace text processor values
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Once you capture the `value` then use [`Nifi expression language`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#plus) to `add 5`.

```
${'$1':toNumber():plus(5)}
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428510/is-it-possible-to-remove-white-spaces-from-the-csv-files-header-name-in-nifi) link for more details regards to similar thread.